# My image inside the div isn't showing without text?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to insert an image under my navbar. I either encounter an issue with the navbar covering the image, the image not scaling properly as I minimize to mobile width, or the image not showing up at all. This is as close as I get to contain the responsiveness, which I want. Any suggestions? I know all the divs are at 0 and need a height, but if I add a height to the image, it will not be responsive.

```css
body{
 background: silver;
}
#pageOne {
  background: url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/21entzo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 56px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Frank's Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myPortfolio.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Frank Lucas</a>
    </div> <!-- Navbar header -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="">About Me</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Contact Me</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- End Container-->
 </nav>  <!--End navbar -->

<div id="pageOne">
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</div>
 


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I know all the divs are at 0 and need a height, but if I add a height to the image, it will not be responsive.`  You've already answered your own question.  Your `<div>` needs a height in order to show a `background`.  Add a height and add `@media` breakpoints to alter as needed for responsiveness.

Comment: @Robert C  is right, also you are defining your margin in pixels which means it will remain the same irrespective of your screen size (width in pixels). Either move to "@media" to create breakpoints or a worse, temporary testing solution could be moving to % instead of px.

Comment: Just a note @Alan, that the `margin` of the `div` being in `px` isn't an issue in itself - it's to counteract the menu being fixed and at a height of `50px`, and prevent the image/content slipping under the nav. I would recommend setting the `padding-top` of the `body` to do this, rather than on individual elements (when using a fixed-nav). I've explained this in an answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must give height to your `div with id #pageOne` so that it will cover a part of screen.
 Here I have scaled the `#pageOne` `height relative to viewport height` .

```css
body{
 background: silver;
}
#pageOne {
  background: url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/21entzo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 56px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Frank's Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myPortfolio.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Frank Lucas</a>
    </div> <!-- Navbar header -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="">About Me</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Contact Me</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- End Container-->
 </nav>  <!--End navbar -->

<div id="pageOne">
  
</div>
 


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In case `vh` isn't supported by the browser (I've experienced this before), also set a height in `em` or `px`, *above* the property using `vh`. Then, if the browser does not support `vh`, `em` or `px` will be used as a fall-back value instead

Answer (score 0):

> I know all the divs are at 0 and need a height

**You've kind of answered your own question**, there.

`div`s with no content (or other-than-default `position` property set) collapse their height.

---

### Show me how!

See my JSFiddle, here: https://jsfiddle.net/5pu2h9tr/1/

```
#pageOne {
    background: url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/21entzo.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-top: 56px;
    height: 20em;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Explanation is below :)

---

### How do I make it appear, and still be responsive?

You're on the right track with needing to set a height. Rather than using `px` values, however, there are other measurements and cool CSS properties which you can take advantage of.

**Use `vh` instead of `px`/`em`**

You could simply set the height of the `div` using **`vh`**, and then use the `background-size` property to contain the image nicely within your `div`. Like so:

```
height: 50vh; // Uses 50% of the viewport height
height: 100vh; // Uses 100% of the viewport height
height: 33vh; // Uses 33% of the viewport height
// And so on...
```

*Note that some browsers (for some reason) don't support the `vh` measurement, and you will need to provide a fall-back value (otherwise you're back at square one). I find using an `em` value **above** the `vh` value is a good practice, to ensure compatibility.*

For example:

```
height: 20em; // fall-back value
height: 50vh; // if the browser supports vh, this will be used (overrides the value above)
```

*Have a play and see what `em`/`px` fall-back value suits your needs.*

**Fill the `div` with the image as the background**

In order to make your image fill the `div` nicely, you could use `background-size: cover`, which makes the image look neat across all screen sizes (within reason - given a good-resolution/quality image).

```
background-size: cover;
```

You can then set where you want the `cover`'s position origin to be set at - e.g. the `center` horizontally, and the `center` vertically; in that order (change these as you wish).

```
background-position: center center; // Set the center of the image as the origin
background-position: center top; // Set the center of the image (left/right) and the top of the image as the origin.
```

*The best way for you to find the best origin for your needs is to have a play about, and resize your browser window to find what suits you.*

---

#### On a further note:

Rather than setting your `margin-top` of the header to be the "same" as your nav-bar's - set the `padding-top` of your body, instead. This will save you having to re-use the same `margin-top: 56px...` code for the first element of **every** page!

---

Hope this helps!

Any questions, just ask! :)

Comment: The top of the image is cut off in your example Geoffrey!

Comment: That's due to the origin of where the image is being positioned. You can always change it to be `center top` and it will place the origin at the top of the image :)

Comment: Much better Geoff!

Comment: @GeoffJames Hey Geoffrey, thanks for the input. I changed the following to this, but I wanted to know if it was possible to have the image in the same position as what it looks like with the keyboard and mouse as it scales to half the screen? It may sound a bit weird on how I phrased it. In shorter terms, is the image zoomed in like that because of the css, or rather the image itself?  Also I tried the margin thing on the body, but the div was in another section. Am I missing something? I'm fairly new to front end development and your vh and em examples were really helpful!

Comment: {
 background: silver;
}
#pageOne {
  background: url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/o0qyvn.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top, center center;
    height: 30em;
    height: 75vh;
    margin-top: 52px;
}

Comment: @GeoffJames Also, instead of a div, I've been searching around, could I have just put it inside a header?

Comment: Hi @Frank - The way the image scales is down to the `cover` value of the `background-size` property. The other popular value to use is `contain`, but this does crop the image depending on the aspect ratio etc. It's to do with the CSS. You could always counteract this with an image with more space around the object you're focusing on. Not sure with the issue you're having to do with the `body` - just check it's `padding-top`, not `margin-top` as you mentioned in your comment. And AFAIK `header` renders (and is) the same as a `div`, it's just an element type in HTML5 and is to do with semantics

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
#pageOne {
    background: url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/21entzo.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 56px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

YOu need contain and 100% height and width.

Comment: This will not work. What are you setting the `height`/`width` to `100%` of?

Comment: Great - a screenshot..! Still doesn't answer the question, though -.-

Comment: It doesn't answer the question? Are you some kind of code police and need to be rude like this. The screen video shows that I put set height of 100% and background contain on the div #pageOne. Also, that it works for what the gentleman that asked for help.

Comment: I should clarify - the question that I asked *"what are you setting the height and width to `100%` of?"*

Comment: And you got your answer!

Comment: Had another look at your screenshot, and still can't see what you're setting it relative to I'm afraid, hence why I asked. Sorry if you got offended by me asking a question and trying to give you some constructive criticism. Might it be worth putting your screenshot into your answer, to help support it?

Comment: I apologize back, I took your question as offensive as you stated that it will not work and it clearly does. The same outcome as your answer below.  I will listen to you though as you probably have more experience and will try to learn from your answer.